# sub class does acquire the interface implemented by the superclass?

Tags: java, interface, extends

just a little question that can be stupid but i want to be sure of this. If i got 2 classes: ClassA and ClassB declared in this way

```
public ClassA implements Usable... //Usable is an interface obviously
...

public ClassB extends ClassA ...
...
```

Does ClassB implement Usable?

EDIT 
And if the answer is yes if i ll write this declaration below

```
public ClassB extends ClassA implements Usable
```

what will happen ? eclipse doesn't show me errors but i want to know if there will be in some way

Comment: Yes, it does implement `Usable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public ClassB extends ClassA implements Usable` is equivalent to just 
`public ClassB extends ClassA`.  As you have already extended `ClassA` which implements all methods in your interface `Usable`, Eclipse wont show any errors (compilation) Both of these work:

```
Usable usable = new ClassA();
Usable usable = new ClassB();
```

Answer (score 1):

Every Child is Parent.

So it is. You may not seeing it directly but those methods getting inherited .